# Access is denied when installing Google APIs

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, android-sdk-2.1

When installing Google APIs for level 7 in Eclipse with the SDK Manager, I got the error:

> File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\google_apis-7_r01.zip (Access is denied)
>   Done. Nothing was installed

Is this to be expected?

Comment: Same thing for level 8; I have the Google APIs for everything above that installed - from 2.3.3 to 14 (4.0)/ICS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are on windows run eclipse with elevated privileges(right click and run as admin) whenever you are doing any updates via eclipse.

Comment: I tried that (changed the app to target 2.2, and changed the AVD used) and got this in the Console tab:

[2011-11-24 11:19:33 - WRYResp] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK
[2011-11-24 11:19:33 - WRYResp] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2011-11-24 11:19:33 - WRYResp] Launch canceled!

Logcat didn't seem to have anything around that time that corresponded, though...

Comment: I could swear the answer I responded to above and the one I see there now are not the same; anyway, I did that and it worked fine. Thanks!

Comment: I had this problem when updating from SDK Manager on Windows 8.1 and   running SDK Manager as admin resolved it.